# ERROR EXCEPTION while printing message raised: type_error on plunit run_tests

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, plunit

These are defined in chess.pl

```
:- dynamic drop/1.
:- dynamic start/1.

a_drop(X) :- piese(X), piese_pos(X, Y), \+ on(Y), assertz(drop(X)).
a_pickup(X) :- retract(drop(_-_-X)).
a_clear:- retract(drop(_)).

print_drops:- forall(drop(X), write(X)).


on(X) :- once(drop(_-_-X)).
off(X) :- \+ drop(_-_-X).
```

I have this test file:

```
:- begin_tests(chess).

:- include(chess).

clear_board :- a_clear.

  board_1_setup :- a_drop(b-r-(b-6)), a_drop(w-k-(d-5)), a_drop(w-b-(c-4)), a_drop(b-b-(b-3)).

test(hello, [
  setup(board_1_setup),
  cleanup(clear_board)
]) :- on(b-4).


:- end_tests(chess).
```

When I run this command:
`swipl -g run_tests -t halt _chess.plt`

This is the output.

```
% PL-Unit: chess
ERROR:
    [[ EXCEPTION while printing message url('/home/eguneys/chess/pro/_chess.plt':10)
       with arguments []:
       raised: type_error(text,url('/home/eguneys/chess/pro/_chess.plt':10))
    ]]
:
        test hello: failed

 done
% 1 test failed
% 0 tests passed
ERROR: -g run_tests: false
```

I expected the test to fail, but with a friendlier message, what is this ERROR garbage.

Please help.

Tests passes normal when I test for example: `... :- on(b-6).`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in the development version (`ppa:swi-prolog/devel`).

There appear to be typos or things missing in your test files:

```
$ swipl -g run_tests -t halt chess.plt


% PL-Unit: chess 
ERROR: /tmp/chess.plt:9:
    error in setup: plunit_chess:a_drop/1: Unknown procedure: plunit_chess:piese/1
 done
% No tests to run
```